# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, php, mysql

So at first I was getting this error when trying to create databases for use in phpmyadmin. `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

I looked in several places and a buddy of mine told me to just attempt to re install mysql since I just re-installed the server yesterday.

So I decided to re install mysql, and now I can't even run the installer without getting this error: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I had also got the `'root'@'localhost'` error when trying to install a script with the database I created. This is the error I get when I had tried to install the script: 
Running Centos 6

[image]

PHP 5.3.3 (Script I am using is Ioncubed, and  PHP 5.4, I don't need it).

EDIT:

If you are going to question about why don't I look around first, I have looked around! I ain't having luck finding others who had the type of issue as I did.

EDIT 2:

I successfully installed MySQL now. I felt like going back and giving it another go and the installer went fine. But I still get the root@localhost error provided in the image above. I already checked to make sure the config wasn't magically using "root"@"localhost".

Comment: It looks like you have a wrong password set. Did you try [recovery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)?

Comment: @week I actually just edited the post. I solved the installer, I just can't figure out the root@localhost. Check "Edit 2:" at the bottom.

Comment: My comment was about error `root@localhost password NO` error. Can you connect from shell as db root?

Answer (score 1):

Configuration of the database does use root@localhost, and that password was chosen when you installed it for the first time. It is not the system's root password. MySQL root and system's root are different accounts with possible different passwords.

Try to remember and try to guess it by using `mysql -u root -p` to try. If no luck, search Google for how to remove MySQL configuration and start anew.

Comment: I do know the password, I can log into mysql perfectly fine. Not sure if you are talking about the database or the mysql root login.

Comment: My friend said to try my root mysql login and it worked fine. I just don't get what is incorrect with my other login...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL treats differently "localhost" and "127.0.0.1"; the first is used to run a Unix socket connection on `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` or whatever. So you need two different `GRANT` instructions in your `mysql.user` table (at least I do on OpenSuSE Linux; on e.g. Windows your mileage may vary):

(mysql connection as root)

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES (*or privilege list*) ON yourdb.* TO user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES (*or privilege list*) ON yourdb.* TO user@127.0.0.1 IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then, it is obvious that your script is indeed trying to install as "root@localhost". If you can't edit the script or the installer config, you can work through that by **temporarily** disabling root password:

```
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET Password = NULL WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

...for greater safety, *do not logout from mysql* after doing this. After the install has completed, you will have to reset the root password:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This does not solve the problem of **what does the script do after install**. Chances are that it will *still* use root at localhost, and *still* use no password. So as soon as you reset the password, it will stop working. You need to find references to root and localhost (they may be specified separately) in the script's config: there must be something like

```
user = root
host = localhost
dbname = somedb
```

or maybe

```
'username' => 'root',
"hostaddr" => "localhost",
...
```

and change them. You can create a new user in MySQL by just issuing a new `GRANT` statement.

Comment: Will give this a go and report back. But actually I use to have this script installed on a HostGator server and never experienced this issue. Switched to VPS hosting for the Centos CML experience and speeds.

Comment: Ok weird, everything is working fine with the database that I had set the script to now.

Comment: Ok so it's not working again. I decided to do a re install with a new database.

Comment: Hey Iserni I came back looking at your post to see if I could alter in in anyway to make this work. Since now it is trying to use apache@localhost I ran the command `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON rgctravis.* TO apache@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'passhere';`  That changed nothing. But when I remove all text out of the password field, the script says "No Database Selected". Any suggestions?

Comment: You also need to issue a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` to ensure the password change "takes". If at that point it *still* not works, then the password you set is not the one the script is using. Maybe there are *two* config files (as in "a default one and an incorrectly named/placed one").

Comment: Yah had done the Flush Priv's. I just installed the script on a Hostgator server and it installed 100% fine without issue, I don't think it'd mean the script magically changed when getting on my server..

Comment: There seems to be either server configuration issues or privilege problems. I'm afraid you'll have to take it to the sysadmins: as you say, it's not likely the script changed upon changing server.

Answer (score 0):

In normal cases, [stack_overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533441/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-after-password-r) is helpful.
However, in case of conflict of different version, password can not reset successfully. In this case, please re-install the mysql. **That is what i meet!!**

Here is the steps:
1) find the installed mysql
 # rpm -qa|grep mysql

2) remove the mysql
#rpm -e 'the programe'

3)delete the lib&include
#rm -rf /usr/lib/mysql
#rm -rf /usr/include/mysql

4)delelte the mysql date or backup it.
#mv /var/lib/mysql ~/mysql_backup

5)reinstall mysql
#yum install mysql mysql-server

6)start mysql service and try it
#chkconfig mysqld on
#service mysqld start
#mysql -uroot -p
  --in this step, if install succeed, the password should be null. just press enter and get into mysql database.